# Can't test class containing import nestJS

Tags: mocha.js, nestjs, sinon, typeorm

I am trying to build unit test for my service implemented in nodeJS.
I understood that I can't use import in my test files so I used only require in my test files:

```
const typeorm = require("typeorm");
const DeviceService = require("./device.service.ts");
const Device = require("./entities/device.entity.ts");
const CreateDeviceDto = require("./dto/create-device.ts");
```

The problem is that I have an import in my deviceService.

When I run my test, I have an error from my file device.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

For information, I try in my test to create my service with a stub like this:

```
const deviceRepository = typeorm.getRepository(Device);

const stub = sinon.stub(deviceRepository, "create").returns(stubValue);
const DeviceServiceStubbed = new DeviceService(deviceRepository);
```

Stack used: nestJs / Chai / Sinon / Typeorm

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my mocha call was wrong.
I changed   `"test": "mocha"` to `"test": "mocha  --require ts-node/register`
in my package.json and now it works fine